# Maximum level of recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion

What's the maximum level of recursion and how do I change it in Python?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289430/python-recursion

Comment: lol!! loving it! Just like http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=recursion

Comment: @Zeus, I tried to close this as a duplicate of itself. Too bad it didn't work.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The default is 1000 levels deep and you can change that using the `setrecursionlimit` function in the `sys` module.

***Warning:***

Beware that some operating systems may start running into problems if you go much higher due to limited stack space.

Answer (score 6):

Thought I will add a code example:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)
```

As Lizard noted, default is 1000 for a reason and the warning is important. Trying a high recursion limit on fibonacci(10000) ( return f(n-1) + f(n-2) ) was enough to shut down my Python IDE. Not getting the 'recursion depth reached' warning did not mean the problem was solved.