# program stops unexpectedly

Tags: python, exception, overflow

I wrote ths program that is supposed to print out the prime numbers between 100 and 200. (I added some extra print commands along the way so I could see where it was getting to.) Can anyone give me a hint as to why it stops at 137, while the script is checking this number?

Thanks!

Here is the script:

```
import math
import sys
index=100.0
checker=2.0

def start():
    print("A")
    global index
    while index<=200.0:
        fu1()
    if index>200.0:
        end()

def fu1():
    print ("B")
    print ("checker", checker)
    print ("index", index)
    global index
    global checker
    varb=index/checker
    varb2=round(index/checker, 0)
    if checker>=index:
        print ("C")
        print(index)
        index=index+1.0
        checker=2.0
        start()
    if varb2==varb:
        print("D")
        checker=2.0
        index=index+1.0
        start()
    checker=checker+1.0
    fu1()


def end():
    print("E")
    print("ENDED")
    sys.exit()

start()
```

Comment: Maybe this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289430/python-recursion

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - recursion? ;)  Although somewhat odd-looking recursion, I'll admit.

Comment: "Why does fu1 call itself? – David Schwartz " --It calls itself to begin that same process again, but with the next higher "index". The program actually works, but is there a different way it should be done?

Comment: You should use `while` loops for code that will be run an indeterminate number of times. In this case, you have a fixed range to iterate over, so use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: @Peter - Thanks, I checked into the incursion limits, changed it to 5000  and it works up to 200, but it still crashes if I change it to check for primes higher than 1,000,000, which is the original goal.  Instead of this recursion with "while" can you suggest another type?  Obviously, I am just getting the hang of this, and your hint would be very helpful.

Comment: This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python

Answer (score 2):

your program has reached a limit in the number of recursive calls (default to 1000 in python, I think)... you can increase it by using this command `sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)` for instance.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much. I  did that and it worked. But could you tell me one more thing please. After it finishes printing all the primes up to 200 and then prints "End" it prints a whole lot of red messages like this:   File "
  File "C:\Users\Marcela\Documents\HH.txt", line 27, in fu1
    start()
  File "C:\Users\Marcela\Documents\HH.txt", line 12, in start
    end()
  File "C:\Users\Marcela\Documents\HH.txt", line 34, in end
    sys.exit()
SystemExit   Could you tell me now to avoid this?

Comment: Thanks again -- it works, but not for checking larger numbers. It seems (by Weronika's comment) that I  have created  problem recalling Fu1 with "While" -- if you have a suggestion about how to make this process recur in the correct way, please let me know.