# Sorting data hierarchically

Tags: python, list, sorting, set, hierarchical-data

My python program returns a list containing data of sub-list. Each sub-list contains the unique id of an article and the parent id of that article viz

```
pages_id_list ={ {22, 4},{45,1},{1,1}, {4,4},{566,45},{7,7},{783,566}, {66,1},{300,8},{8,4},{101,7},{80,22}, {17,17},{911,66} }
```

In each *sub*-list, the data is structured this way `{*article_id*, *parent_id*}`
If the article_id and parent_id are the same it obviously mean that article has no parent.

I would like to sort the data using minimal code such that for each article, I can readily
access a list of it's children and grandchildren (nested data) if available. For example (using the example data above) I should be able to print at the end of the day:

```
 1
 -45
 --566
 ---783
 -66
 --911
```

.... for article id 1

I could only sort out the highest level (Ist and 2nd generation) ids. Having problem getting the 3rd and subsequent generations.

This is the code I used:

```
highest_level = set()
first_level = set()
sub_level = set()

for i in pages_id_list:
    id,pid = i['id'],i['pid']

    if id == pid:
        #Pages of the highest hierarchy
        highest_level.add(id)

for i in pages_id_list:
    id,pid = i['id'],i['pid']

    if id != pid :
        if pid in highest_level:
            #First child pages
            first_level.add(id)
        else:
            sub_level.add(id)
```

My code sadly does not work.

Any help/nudge in the right direction will be appreciated. 
Thanks

David

Comment: Have you tried using a `while` loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

pages_id_list = [ (22, 4),(45,1),(1,1), (4,4),(566,45),(7,7),(783,566), (66,1),(300,8),(8,4),(101,7),(80,22), (17,17),(911,66) ]

class Node:
    def __init__ (self, article):
        self.article = article
        self.children = []
        self.parent = None

    def print (self, level = 0):
        print ('{}{}'.format ('\t' * level, self.article) )
        for child in self.children: child.print (level + 1)

class Tree:
    def __init__ (self): self.nodes = {}

    def push (self, item):
        article, parent = item
        if parent not in self.nodes: self.nodes [parent] = Node (parent)
        if article not in self.nodes: self.nodes [article] = Node (article)
        if parent == article: return
        self.nodes [article].parent = self.nodes [parent]
        self.nodes [parent].children.append (self.nodes [article] )

    @property
    def roots (self): return (x for x in self.nodes.values () if not x.parent)

t = Tree ()
for i in pages_id_list: t.push (i)
for node in t.roots: node.print ()
```

This creates a tree structure which you can traverse in order to get all subitems. You can access any article via `t.nodes [article]` and get its children via `t.nodes [article].children`.

The output of the print method is:

```
1
    45
        566
            783
    66
        911
4
    22
        80
    8
        300
7
    101
17
```

Comment: +1 for node/tree objects - IMHO much more understandable. You might even be able to override the `__str__` function instead of using `node.print()`?

Comment: Also bear in mind that Python will throw an error if you recurse more than 1000 levels deep. (This part: `child.print (level + 1)`)

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289430/maximum-level-of-recursion-in-python)

Comment: If it is to be expected that the tree will have more then 1000 levels, you should derecursify the print function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach (assuming your page id list elements are not sets, as your code suggests):

```
from collections import defaultdict

page_ids = [
    (22, 4), (45, 1), (1, 1), (4, 4),
    (566, 45), (7, 7), (783, 566), (66, 1), (300, 8),
    (8, 4), (101, 7), (80, 22), (17, 17), (911, 66)
]

def display(id, nodes, level):
    print('%s%s%s' % ('  ' * level, '\\__', id))
    for child in sorted(nodes.get(id, [])):
        display(child, nodes, level + 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nodes, roots = defaultdict(set), set()

    for article, parent in page_ids:
        if article == parent:
            roots.add(article)
        else:
            nodes[parent].add(article)

    # nodes now looks something like this:
    # {1: [45, 66], 66: [911], 4: [22, 8], 22: [80], 
    #  7: [101], 8: [300], 45: [566], 566: [783]}

    for id in sorted(roots):
        display(id, nodes, 0)
```

Output would be:

```
\__1
  \__45
    \__566
      \__783
  \__66
    \__911
\__4
  \__8
    \__300
  \__22
    \__80
\__7
  \__101
\__17
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/4472070

Comment: @Hyperboreus, I explain it in my answer.

Comment: Miku this is useful to know though I prefer a solution without need of module. Never had done much with the collections module before now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to sort the data using minimal code

I read this until now and therefore I will provide another answer. I will not edit my previous answer, because they are really not related. If you want to transfer your list of tuples into a tree structure with minimal code, then this approach is quite minimal, although it can still be minimized further (e.g. using a recursive lambda term instead of the function):

```
pages_id_list = [ (22, 4),(45,1),(1,1), (4,4),(566,45),(7,7),(783,566), (66,1),(300,8),(8,4),(101,7),(80,22), (17,17),(911,66) ]

def getTree (item, pages): return [ (x, getTree (x, pages) ) if getTree (x, pages) else x for x in (x [0] for x in pages if x [1] == item) ]

tree = getTree (None, [ (x [0], None if x [0] == x [1] else x [1] ) for x in pages_id_list] )
```

Comment: Thanks for this Hyperboreus. This is most useful to me because of the minimal code.

Comment: Bear in mind though that the computational cost its horrendous.