# Tree Building Logic Trouble

Tags: python

I am writing a simple app that incorporates a tree that represents the English language. I have done something similar in C++, but this is my first venture at building a tree in Python.

```
englishWords = []
englishFile = open("english.txt")
for line in englishFile:
    englishWords.append(line.rstrip())

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.Value = value
        self.checked = False
        self.Pointers = []
        self.numPointers = 0
    def addNode(self, value):
        x = Node(value)
        self.Pointers.append(x)
        return x

headString = "HEAD"
Head = Node(headString)

def buildPointers(parent, info, nodeList):  

    x = 0
    y = len(nodeList)
    while x < y :
        if parent.numPointers == 0:
            newNode = parent.addNode(info)
            parent.numPointers = parent.numPointers + 1
            buildPointers(newNode, nodeList[x+1], nodeList)
            break
        else:
            for i in parent.Pointers:
                if info == i.Value:
                    buildPointers(i, nodeList[x+1], nodeList)
                    continue
                else:   
                    newNode = parent.addNode(info)
                    parent.numPointers = parent.numPointers + 1
                    buildPointers(newNode, nodeList[x+1], nodeList)
                    continue


def treeBuild(lyst):
    for i in lyst:
        iList = list(i)
        buildPointers(Head, iList[0], iList)

treeBuild(englishWords)
```

As soon as I run the code Windows says "python.exe has stopped running" it's probably something simple that I have overlooked, so feel free to rip into me or the way I wrote this. I would love any criticism that will help make me a better programmer.

Comment: You should run this code in some terminal window or IDE so you can view the traceback.

Comment: Running it, I'm getting a `RuntimeError` due to excess recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this isn't really pythonic, numerous errors here but I guess the main issue would be using too much recursion, something python "out of the box" isn't very good at.

It limits default recursion depth to 1000 steps. and you probably need more. here is a question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289430/maximum-level-of-recursion-in-python) explaining how to change this default.

also another good advice would be changing the recursion to use generators like in this [blog post](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201205/recursive_dogma.html)

p.s: since you don't change the value of x the while loop might run forever in some cases wouldn't it? (I didn't fully understand the algorithm so I'm not sure)

**EDIT:** to make this a little more pythonic I would change the populating part to use with context manager:

```
with open("english.txt") as english_file:
   for line in english_file ..
```

BTW a much better way, not loading million strings into a list would be changing the populating part to a generator function, yielding an english word everytime - much more efficient and pythonic. you can read about context managers and generator functions [here](http://www.tp.umu.se/~nylen/fnm/pylect/advanced/advanced_python/index.html)

**Another edit: learining idiomatic python** The best place to start would be opening a python shell and:

```
import this
```

the "zen of python" would appear. 
a good opinionated guide to modern python development including libs, best practice, reading recommendations and writing idomatic python would be [Hitchhikers guide to python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/) by kenneth reitz.

and a similar source, more focused one, is [writing idiomatic Python](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/10/04/writing-idiomatic-python/)

good luck!

Comment: Thanks man this is my first venture into algorithmic logic without pointers. I didn't put it in my example but I have the recursion depth set to 60000. My real problem was simple. I overlooked the fact that I was not changing x. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you are welcome. I'll edit my answer with some pythonic best practice

Comment: Thanks man That really helps. If there is any other documentation that you know that would be good for me to exploit the benefits of Python instead of just forcing it into a super wack translation of C++, That would be great!

Comment: @sir_charles804 you're welcome. I'll edit the answer with more reference

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually reducing the nodeList when you recurse causing the infinite recursion. You will also not break out of the loop properly when you finish processing a word. The following buildnodelist completes at the very least. I won't guarantee that it works as desired though since I only modified some blocking lines:

```
def buildPointers(parent, info, nodeList):
    if parent.numPointers == 0:
        newNode = parent.addNode(info)
        parent.numPointers = parent.numPointers + 1
        if len(nodeList) > 1:
            buildPointers(newNode, nodeList[x+1], nodeList[1:])
    else:
        for i in parent.Pointers:
            if info == i.Value:
                if len(nodeList) > 1:
                    buildPointers(i, nodeList[x+1], nodeList[1:])
            else:
                newNode = parent.addNode(info)
                parent.numPointers = parent.numPointers + 1
                if len(nodeList) > 1:
                    buildPointers(newNode, nodeList[x+1], nodeList[1:])
```

Essentially, I've removed the While loop and passed slices of the 1st element of nodeList if it has more than 1 item in it.